# Exporting decorated Class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have a TypeScript class and added a decorator over methods to measure their latency.
If I export the class directly I get the error:

```
export class DB{
@latency
public async writeToDB(itemID:string){
...
}
}
```

ReferenceError: DB is not defined

But if I modify the code to be like, I don't get the error. Could somebody explain this?:

```
class DB{
@latency
public async writeToDB(itemID:string){
...
}
}
export {DB};
```

The latency method

```
export function latency() {
  return function (originalMethod, context) {
    async function decoratedMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      const start = process.hrtime();
      const result = await originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
      const end = process.hrtime(start);
      const executionTime = (end[0] * 1e9 + end[1]) / 1e6; // Convert to milliseconds
      console.log(executionTime);
      return result;
    }
    return decoratedMethod;
  };
}
```

Why am I getting reference error in first scenario? Is it due to how decorators are compiled to javascript?

I tried checking the contents of js file and noticed in first case:
export is like
export.DB = (()=>{})() i.e. an IIFE directly

whereas in second scenario. Its

let DB = = (()=>{})();
exports.DB = DB;